# Can I use two different clientId and clientSecret values in app.config file with PayPal API in c#?

Tags: c#, paypal, app-config, paypal-rest-sdk

Is there any reasonable way to use two different clientId and clientSecret values within the same C# Winforms app?

Here's why I want to do it: I have an internal company application that performs PayPal refunds for customers - some are from our US PayPal account and some are from our UK PayPal account. Because they are from different accounts, I'll need to create two PayPal apps and be granted two different sets of secure clientId and clientSecret values. I'd really like the Winforms application to be capable of refunding either account, but at this point, I have only successfully been able to do refunds by using the PayPal API in conjunction with having this following code in the app.config file.

```
  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="live" />
      <add name="clientId" value="AZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="ELxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
```

If I have to, I'll create a separate refund application for our UK account, but it seems like there must be a reasonable way to do this within one application.

From what I can tell, while there may be some ways to change the app.config file, everyone seems to be saying that this is a terrible idea and even if you managed to do it that your application would restart.

So I guess what I'm asking is, is there any way to change the value of clientId and clientSecret during runtime without actually causing a restart of the program? Or, alternatively, is there some other method of getting an accesstoken from the PayPal API that will allow me to specify the clientId and clientSecret at runtime?

---

Update - after reading Erik Philip's answer below, I tried commenting out the clientId and clientSecret in my app.config file and then instead of this code to authorize:

```
    var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
    var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
    var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
```

I added this instead:

```
    var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
    config.Add("clientId", "AZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    config.Add("clientSecret", "ELxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
    var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
```

This worked great,I later added an if() statement in there to check whether it's a UK order or not and changed the clientId and clientSecret accordingly.

Comment: Does not paypay have a Constructor based configuration too?

Answer (score 2):

According to their own [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/environment/), you can.

Excerpt:

using PayPal.Api;

```
// Get a reference to the config
var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

// Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
```

Since `ConfigManager` is creating the instance, you can either create your own instance, or take this instance and change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I think this put me on the right path! I'm pretty new to c# and still don't really have a great grasp of things like app.config files but this really helped me get there.